# changing the Interval of IConnectableObservable

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have a method called `Subscribe()` where am doing this :-

```
private void Subscribe(){
            IObservable<long> timer = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250), Scheduler.NewThread);
            IConnectableObservable<long> TimerPublisher = timer.Publish();
            TimerPublisher.Connect();

            this.DisposeMonsterAction = TimerPublisher.Subscribe(tick => MonsterAction());

            var timer = from tick in world.TimerPublisher where tick % 1 == 0 select tick;
            this.DisposeMonstersDeath = timer .Subscribe(tick => MonstersDeath());
}
```

so that `MonsterAction()` being called every 250ms , and then `MonsterDeath` being called every 1sec, but it's not working like that , `MonsterDeath` being called every 250ms, so how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Is there an explicit reason you need a `ConnectableObservable`?

Comment: The `Connect` method returns an `IDisposable` that you need to manage too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why you are using "hot" observerables here (likely due to other code?), but the simplest way to combine two discrete time streams like this is with `Merge`:

```
Action MonsterAction = 
    () => Console.WriteLine("MonsterAction");
Action MonsterDeath = 
    () => Console.WriteLine("MonsterDeath");

// action stream
var monsterAction = Observable
    .Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250))
    .Do(_ => MonsterAction());

// death stream
var monsterDeath = Observable
    .Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000))
    .Do(_ => MonsterDeath());

// act, act, act, act + die, act, act, ...
var obs = monsterAction.Merge(monsterDeath);

// "warm up" the cold observable
var hotObs1 = obs.Publish();

using(var conn = hotObs1.Connect())
using(var x = hotObs1.Subscribe(evt => Console.WriteLine(evt)))
{
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the rather odd sharing of the interval sequence and the use of NewThread, your problem seems to squarely lie with

```
where tick % 1 == 0
```

which I can only imagine needs to read

```
where tick % 4 == 0 //or ==3 or whatever...
```

ie, any integer/long value divided by 1 has a remainder of 0, thus your where clause is pointless.

Other tips that you may find useful:

1. Put your subscriptions before your connection. i.e. if you continue to use the Connectable observable put the .Connect() line as the last line in the method.
2. Consider injecting in the scheduler you are using so you can test
3. Consider using the Task or ThreadPool scheduler. They are fine for simple Timer/Interval scheduling. A NewThread seems like a big hammer for the job.
4. Use the _ character to indicate you are not using a parameter. E.g. the Action where you call the MonsterAction() and MonsterDeath you can change to (_=>MonsterAction()). This expresses to the next developer that you dont actually use the parameter.
5. I would rename your DisposeMonsterAction/DisposeMonstersDeath to MonsterActionSubscription & MonstersDeathSubscription.
6. I dont think you gain anything from sharing a sequence. Under the hood it is the scheduler that is really doing the work. I would actually imagine that checking the value 4 times a second would actually cost more than using two sequences.

I would suggest that for the sake of your fellow team mates (including future you) that this is simple enough for your needs

```
private void Subscribe(IScheduler timerScheduler){
    this.DisposeMonsterAction = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250), timerScheduler).Subscribe(_ => MonsterAction());
    this.DisposeMonstersDeath = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000), timerScheduler).Subscribe(_ => MonstersDeath());
}
```

Or with the rename

```
private void Subscribe(IScheduler timerScheduler){
    this.MonsterActionSubscription = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250), timerScheduler).Subscribe(_ => MonsterAction());
    this.MonstersDeathSubscription = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000), timerScheduler).Subscribe(_ => MonstersDeath());
}
```